# Visual Studio 2017 - Package Management Initialization Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've scoured the forums including this one - the main thing is that they say to delete the privateregistry.bin file and then restart - seems to work for some people but does not work in my case - I keep getting the same problem.

The problem occurs for VS Community, Professional, and Enterprise - version 15.9.2 - on Windows 7 x64

I've deleted old files but nothing seems to work.

Is there anything else that I should look at?[image: Error window when starting VS 2017]

Comment: The activity log is fairly significant so I didn't post it.  I'm just wondering if there's a simple solution for this problem.  In the past Microsoft promised fixes in future updates so I shouldn't be seeing this problem now.

Comment: What was the answer, I am getting this.